# Count recurring sets and add as new column

Tags: pandas, frame

My DataFrame is like:

```
col1   col2  col3
divq   .233     1
divq   .991     2
divq  1.821     3
divq  2.889     1
divq   .121     2
divq   .337     3
```

I need a new col that tracks/counts col3 and adds its occurrence. So in the ex above, a new col4 would be looking for sequence of values 1, 2, 3 and mark that as the first occurrence then continue and locate second occurrence of 1-3:

```
col4
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

*In my real data frame, there are 10 iterations of the above.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) column 3:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby('col3')
```

Then (taking an arbitrary column) use a [transformation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to enumerate the results of each group:

```
In [12]: g['col1'].transform(lambda x: np.arange(len(x)))
Out[12]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

And set this as column 4:

```
In [13]: df['col4'] = g['col1'].transform(lambda x: np.arange(len(x)))

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   col1   col2  col3 col4
0  divq  0.233     1    0
1  divq  0.991     2    0
2  divq  1.821     3    0
3  divq  2.889     1    1
4  divq  0.121     2    1
5  divq  0.337     3    1
```

Comment: I was writing up a version using `groupby` and `apply`, but this works too. :^)

Comment: That does it for me, Andy. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, thanks to whomever made the edit to my poorly formed data example in the OP!  It is so difficult posting from a phone!

Comment: @AndyHayden seems like a common question, cookbook?

Comment: @Jeff it does... I wonder if there is an easier way to do it, I'm sure I've used/seen a neater solution than arange(len(x)).

Comment: ``df.groupby('col3')['col1'].apply(lambda x: Series(np.arange(len(x)),x.index))`` works, but yours is cleaner